# Changing modal content breaks AJAX events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I use jquery-ujs for ajax requests (`data-remote="true"`). My problem is, that the first request is okay, and while the second is running, it breaks. Whenever I call in the events `$('#modal').empty()` or `$('#modal').text('')` or `$('#modal').html('')`, no more events are going to be called.

To be clear, here's the code:

```
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', function () {
    console.log('beforeSend');
    $('#modal').empty().modal('show');
});

$(document).on('ajax:send', function () {
    console.log('send');
});

$(document).on('ajax:success', function (e, xhr) {
    console.log('success');
    $('#modal').html(xhr).drags({ handle: '.modal-header' }).modal('show');

    if (typeof doWork === 'function') {
        doWork();
    }
});

$(document).on('ajax:complete', function () {
    console.log('complete');
});
```

And the console output:

- beforeSend
- send
- success
- complete
- beforeSend

If I move `$('#modal').empty().modal('show');` to the send event, then it is going to be called, but the success method is never called anymore (neither error neither complete, nothing more).

This problem annoys me for more hours now... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to avoid using jquery-ujs events and **using global ajax events**, so my final working code is:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
    $('#modal').empty().modal('show');
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr) {
    $('#modal').html(xhr.responseText).drags({ handle: '.modal-header' }).modal('show');

    if (typeof doWork === 'function') {
        doWork();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to move `empty()` to the `ajax:complete`?
In this case, when your modal closes, it opens empty for the next use and is ready for reuse.
I suggest that you put this command in the last step so that it does not cause any problems.  Like the following:
`$(document).on('ajax:complete', function () { console.log('complete'); . . . . $('#modal').empty(); });`
I believe that this is not the best solution and there are definitely other solutions.  But I hope this solution will solve your problem.

Comment: If I empty the modal immediately the user can't see its content in less than a second.

Comment: How about handle eptying model whenever it closes? I'll poat another answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).empty()
})
```

Comment: Would be a great idea, and might help; but I'm not hiding the modal, as it is a confirmation dialog, and if the user proceeds, it disappears (becomes empty) while the request is performing, and then reappears stating the delete was successful. So technically the hidden event does not fire during this.